# What is the precise meaning of "distribution z=ax induced by the measure"?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, continuity

This thread is more about language clarification. In one paper it is stated that "to the continuity points of the distribution of $z = a  \cdot x $ induced by the measure $ \mu $ on $R^d $ ". No further information about $ \mu $.
a is a scalar and z, x are random variables.

I think it means
if we have a the Function $ f(b) = P ( [ - \infty ; b] ) = \int_{ - \infty } ^b a \cdot x \, d\mu (dx)  $ then we look at the b where f is continue.

Comment: Are $X$ and $Z$ random variables, and $a$ a scalar?

Comment: yes. @RyanWarnick